# Issues with Flexbox in React Native not displaying the Full Text

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm having some troubles displaying information which I believe they have to do with the Flexbox Properties, but no matter how I play around with the Styles I don't get to fit everything in some components.

First I have this Component which is a Simple Card Component where I pass my data from API:

```
<PartidoItem
                    localImage={logoLocal}
                    marcadorLocal={marcadorLocal}
                    time={date}
                    partidoId={partidoId}
                    estatus={estatus}
                    minute={elapsed}
                    estadio={estadio}
                    marcadorVisita={marcadorVisita}
                    visitImage={logoVisita}
                    onSelect={estatus !== 'NS' && estatus !== 'TBD' ? () => {
                        selectPartidoHandler(partidoId, tituloPartido)
                    }
                        : () => { }
                    }
                />
```

This comes from this Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from 'react-native';

import Card from '../UI/Card';
import Colors from '../../constants/Colors';

const PartidoItem = props => {
    let TouchableCmp = TouchableOpacity;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 21) {
        TouchableCmp = TouchableNativeFeedback;
    }

    return (
        <Card style={styles.product}>
            <View style={styles.touchable}>
                <TouchableCmp onPress={props.onSelect} useForeground>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={styles.column}>
                            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                                <Image 
                                resizeMode="cover"
                                style={styles.image} 
                                source={{ uri: props.localImage }} 
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.column}>
                            <Text style={styles.number}>{props.marcadorLocal}</Text>
                        </View>
                        {props.estatus === 'NS' || props.estatus === 'TBD'
                            ? <View style={styles.column}>
                                <Text style={styles.date}>{props.time}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.title}>{props.estadio}</Text>
                            </View>
                            : props.estatus === 'FT' ?
                            <View style={styles.column}>
                                <Text style={styles.title2}>Final</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.title}>{props.estadio}</Text>
                            </View> 
                            :
                            <View style={styles.column}>
                                <Text style={styles.title}>Tiempo:</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.title}>{props.minute} '</Text>
                            </View>
                        }
                        <View style={styles.column}>
                            <Text style={styles.number}>{props.marcadorVisita}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.column}>
                            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                                <Image 
                                resizeMode="cover"
                                style={styles.image} 
                                source={{ uri: props.visitImage }} 
                                />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableCmp>
            </View>
        </Card>

    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    product: {
        height: 100,
        margin: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    touchable: {
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    column: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '100%',
        width: '20%',
    },
    space_between_columns: {
        width: 100
    },
    box: {
        height: 50,
        width: 50
    },
    imageContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '70%',
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        borderTopRightRadius: 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flex: 1,
    },
    hora: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#888',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    number: {
        fontSize: 50,
        marginVertical: 4,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: Colors.secondary,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginVertical: 4,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        //flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 2,
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    title2: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginVertical: 4,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'red',
    },
    date: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginVertical: 4,
        textAlign: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        flexGrow: 1,
        marginHorizontal: 2,
    },
});

export default PartidoItem;
```

Which Holds this Component as well:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

//Importacion de los colores
import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";

const Card = props => {
    return (
        <View style={{...styles.card, ...props.style}}>
            {props.children}
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    card: {
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOpacity: 0.26,
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowRadius: 8,
        elevation: 5,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: Colors.background,
    }
});

export default Card;
```

Now the problem is that when I see it in the Android Emulator and it has large Strings I see this:

[image: Issue in Android]

As you can see the Component is the one in the Primary Box and the Property "Estadio" is too big that doesn't show completely

The same happens when I check this on my iOS device (through Expo):

[image: Issue in iOS]

Is there a way to get this info to fit into that space so it shows the Full Name?

Kind Regards

PD: After Change Advise on first Answer this is the result with the Logos not showing correctly:

[image: Logos Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your styles :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    product: {
        height: 120,
        margin: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    touchable: {
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    column: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '100%',
    },
    space_between_columns: {
        width: 100
    },
    box: {
        height: 50,
        width: 50
    },
    imageContainer: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
        borderTopRightRadius: 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flex: 1,
    },
    hora: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#888',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    number: {
        fontSize: 50,
        marginVertical: 4,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: Colors.secondary,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 14,
        margin: 5,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        //flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flex: 2,
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    title2: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginVertical: 4,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'red',
    },
    date: {
        fontSize: 14,
        marginVertical: 4,
        textAlign: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        flexGrow: 1,
        marginHorizontal: 2,
    },
});
```

Comment: So it worked but now the Logos are not looking correctly, I don't know how to add a Picture in a Comment, so I will added into the main Question for you to see how it got change the logos. Thank you

Comment: Ok edited answer, just play with `imageContainer` `width` and `height` for a good looking images + margin on `title`